# What does the transparent circle around an animal tracker on the compass mean?

Tags: new-world

Randomly, a transparent circle appears around the tracker icon on the compass for an animal:

[image: icon]

I found some speculative [Reddit posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/newworldgame/comments/pm5bim/white_circles_on_compass/) about this, but no solid answers/none of the comments seem to hold true for me.  I thought it might also mean that the animal is the nearest to me, but that doesn't seem to be the case from testing.

What does this transparent circle mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it has nothing to do with quest items, rarity nor proximity. Several users on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/newworldgame/comments/q5lltn/tracked_items_with_a_circle/) say it's just a bug. When new things show up on your compass, they have a circular "ping" that grows and then shrinks back down to nothing, attempting to alert you to their presence. Sometimes they don't go away properly.